# Create search page

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to create a search page in nodejs. In my code, I take input from another page and render results to a separate page:

```
app.post("/searchProcess", async (req, res) => {
const keyWord = req.body.search;

const searchMovies = await Movies.find({
name: { $regex: new RegExp(keyWord) }
})
const countMoviesSearch = await Movies.find({
name: { $regex: new RegExp(keyWord) }
}).countDocuments();

console.log(countMoviesSearch);

// console.log(keyWord);
res.render("searchResults",{
  searchMovies: searchMovies,
  countMoviesSearch: countMoviesSearch
});
});
```

This is my "searchResults" page code

```
<h1>{{searchMovies.name}}</h1>
<h2>{{countMoviesSearch}}</h2>
```

I currently get `countMoviesSearch`, but in `searchmovies.name` I get undefined and my all input variables are same.

Comment: are you check `searchMovies` data by console it?

Comment: no just for check

Comment: Looks like `searchMovies` is an array, while `name` field belong to movie record/object, not `searchMovies` array.

Comment: DAO `find` methods usually return an array instance. If you want to find a single model you should check `findOne` method (or something like this depending on the ORM you are using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find()` method returns a `Cursor` object. You need to call `toArray()` to get an array of documents. Since you have an array, you can access the `.length` property to get the matched movies, to avoid running the same query again

```
app.post("/searchProcess", async (req, res) => {
const keyWord = req.body.search;

const searchMovies = await Movies.find({
name: { $regex: new RegExp(keyWord) }
}).toArray()

const countMoviesSearch = searchMovies.length

console.log(countMoviesSearch);

// console.log(keyWord);
res.render("searchResults",{
  searchMovies: searchMovies,
  countMoviesSearch: countMoviesSearch
});
});
```